# Can a 32 bit process (game) use more than 4gb of video memory?

Tags: memory, graphics-card, 32-bit

With graphic cards coming out in [6gb, 8gb, and 12gb](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100007709%20600499109%20600358543%20600494828&IsNodeId=1&name=8GB) configurations, can x32 bit games actually use that much? or do the games just use the direct X or openGL driver, which provides an interface for the game, but on the back end runs as a x64 application? if not, would it be necessary to have a x64 program in order to use the full amount of graphics memory?

Comment: Use WDDM 1.1 or high video driver.

Comment: @user2813274: 
They can not use that much in a single mapping. They could use that much in chunks. (think of it as max 32 words on a page. You can use multiple pages of 32 words or less). Keeping track of the page number is likely to induce additional overhead though.

Answer (score -1):

In one of the youtube video I watched, the "value" a 32 bit  is equal to is about 4 billion (ie: 2^32), the actual number is bit higher. As the video explains, this number translated into how much ram it can handle.

Whereas a 64 bit is 2^64, which ,because the number is so large, completely eliminates the memory cap.

Oh found it:[here](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=KgiMzKb8dD0)

Comment: And this applies to video memory as well...?

Comment: Video memory is referred to as part of the ram, so...

Comment: It is used mainly for buffering

Comment: No, it does not apply to all of video memory. Only to that part of video memory that the card exposes to the host bus. The card can use FAR more video memory than that.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/aa366778(VS.85).aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_server_2003 sample)

Comment: "Video memory is referred to as part of the ram" Muh?  Care to explain that? (It can be part of shared main memory on some setups but in cases where your graphics card has that much memory as the OP is asking about it almost guaranteed is dedicated [V]RAM on the card itself. That means only the local mapping between the PCs 32bit **address space** and the actively used (by a process) part of the memory on the card needs to be 4GiB of less).

Comment: STTR Those are artificial main memory limits of some Microsoft operating systems. Most of those are not limited by hardware but for marketing reasons.